# Не находит блок до инспекции кода

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь создать букмарклет для увеличения и уменьшения размера текста субтитров в видео-плеере. Текст находится в контейнере `<div class="fp-captions"><p>Тут субтитры</p><br></div>`
При попытке ввести в консоль`javascript:document.querySelector('[class^=fp-captions]').style.fontSize` не находит блок, однако, если проинспектировать элемент субтитров, сразу находится. После этого в консоли код начинает работать и увеличивать текст, но в бурмарклете выдает ошибку, что так же не может найти style. Как можно решить проблему ? Почему блок не находит до того, как проинспектируешь дерево элементов ?

Comment: Может, стоит написать `document.querySelector('.fp-captions')`? Или `document.querySelector('[class^="fp-captions"]')`?

Comment: Так и прописал, до инспекции дерева элементов выдает null, после инспекции находит нужный узел

Comment: А вы уверены что элементы находятся в одном документе? Если вы используете `iframe`, то тогда это может вызвать проблемы.

Comment: Точно, плеер в iframe, как можно обойти ?

Comment: Ну вообще нужно получить сам элемент `iframe`, а уже у него обратится к пропорции `contentDocument`, а уже там запускать `querySelector`. Чтобы получилось вот так: `playerFrameElement.contentDocument.querySelector(...)`

Comment: Благодарю, попробую )

Comment: Не за что, обращайтесь :)

Comment: У `iframe` еще так же есть событие, которое вызывается после загрузки данных в него, на подобии `onload` в `body`